# Global variables in python's multiprocessing.Pool class

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a relatively simply parallelizable problem that is causing way too much problems for me to implement effectively. What is at the core of my program are two matrices and two vectors, one matrix and vector for each of my two calculations I wish to perform.

In code, that means I have

```
import numpy as np
matrices = dict([("type1", np.random.rand(10,10)), ("type2", np.random.rand(10,10))])
vectors = dict([("type1", np.random.rand(10)), ("type2", np.random.rand(10))])
```

What I want to do (not really, but in the simplified case) is this:

I have a very large list of vectors for each type:

```
input_vectors = [np.random.rand(10) for i in range(1000)]
```

and I want to calculate `A*v+b` where `A` is the matrix and `b` is the vector for each type.

The single-thread code that does what I need is therefore

```
def f(input_vector, matricx, vector):
    return np.dot(matrix, input_vector) + vector

results = {}
for type in ['type1', 'type2']:
    results[type] = []
    for input_vector in input_vectors:
        results.append(f(input_vector, matrices[type], vectors[type]))
```

However, I want to do this in parallel. However, I do not know how to solve the problem that the function that I want to map over the list of vectors takes as its input more than just the vectors.

I want to write something like

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(4)
for type in types:
    p.map(lambda x: f(x, matrices[type], vectors[type] , input_vectors))
```

However, that does not work because the lambda function cannot be pickled. One thing that does work is to append the matrix I want to multiply with to each vector, but that of course is not feasible memory-wise.

Any thoughts on how to elegantly solve my conundrum?

---

What I would like is for each element of the pool to have a copy of the matrix and vector it has to multiply with, but I do not know how to do this in `multiprocessing`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to pass multiple arguments to `map`:

```
def f(matrix, vector, input_vector):
    return np.dot(matrix, input_vector) + vector

results = {}
for type_ in types:
    func = partial(f, matrices[type_], vectors[type_])
    results[type_] = p.map(func, input_vectors)
```

If you prefer to pass the entire `matrices` and `vectors` lists to each child when you start up the `Pool`, and then just pass the `type` when you call `map`, you can do that, too. Use the `initializer`/`initargs` arguments to `multiprocessing.Pool` to pass the lists, and then make them global inside the `initializer` function. That will make them global inside each child process:

```
matrices = vectors = None

def init(_matrices, _vectors):
    global matrices, vectors
    matrices = _matrices
    vectors = _vectors


def f(type_, input_vector):
    return np.dot(matrices[type_], input_vector) + vectors[type_]

def main():
    # <declare matrices, vectors, input_vectors here>
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init, 
                             initargs=(matrices, vectors))
    results = {}
    for type_ in ['type1', 'type2']:
        func = partial(f, type_)
        results[type_] = p.map(func, input_vectors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just a subquestion, does this method acually cause each process to have its individual copy of the matrices? If I understand multiprocessing correctly, that should be the case...

Comment: @5xum Conceptually, yes, each process ends up with a separate copy. Now, in practice, if you're using a platform that supports `os.fork()` (like Linux), each process gets a "copy-on-write" version of `matrices`. This means that as long as you don't modify `matrices`, most of the list will actually be shared between the processes. As soon as you try to modify it, though, the process in which you're doing the modification will create a separate copy for whatever kernel page(s) the piece of the list you're modifying lives in.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Windows, but I am worried that if the matrices are not copied to each of the processes, the one matrix may end up locked most of the time (during the execution of the `np.dot()` command) and that I will not get the speed-up I need.

Comment: @5xum You won't have any issues with a matrix being locked up. The copy-on-write behavior is just a memory optimization; you can happily treat `matrices` as if each process has a separate copy.

Comment: That is what I expected by the descriptions of the `subprocess` module, but it's good to hear it from an expert. Thank you very much for all your help.